# Android Custom Dialog Textview and Background Color

Tags: android, text, colors, dialog

I have a custom DialogPreference Dialog that has its layout set out in a relativelayout that contains the following:

- Checkbox
- Textview
- Text Field

This is fine in Android 4.0+, because the theme we are using is Theme.Light so the background color of the dialog is white and the default text is black for the Checkbox label and textview. However, in 2.3.3, the background color is dark grey so it becomes hard to see the text... the theme is still Theme.Light however.

I thought that making a custom dialog would be necessary for this because the checkbox enable/disables the text field. At the moment, I'm making the background color of the relativelayout for this Dialog white... but I don't really like this solution as there maybe cases where some other phones on 2.3.3 may not have white as the default dialog background...

Is there a cleaner way to fix this problem?

I notice this person has the same problem: [Custom Support Dialog Fragment text is the wrong color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15065049/custom-support-dialog-fragment-text-is-the-wrong-color)

Another with the problem :[Android: Issue with showing dialog from Theme.Light activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7771230/android-issue-with-showing-dialog-from-theme-light-activity)

EDIT: Attached screenshot. This is what it looks like on LG Optimus 2X running 2.3.3. On my co-worker's samsung galaxy which runs 2.3.3 also, the background is even darker so you can hardly see the text.

[image]

Comment: You could simply override dialog background in your custom theme, even providing the color you need for 2.3.3 using resource qualifiers. Anyway: please post a screenshot that shows the problem you're facing.

Comment: I would like to keep the OS default styles... i don't want to use 1 custom theme so that dialogs in 2.3.3 and 4.0+ will have the same style... If that is not possible then yes, that's what I will have to do i guess.

Answer (score 0):

You could make custom dialog theme in style files , such as:

```
less than API 11:

<style name="MyDialogTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light" >

API 11 and forward:

<style name="MyDialogTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Dialog" >
```

then use "MyDialogTheme" in your Fragment dialog:

```
... ...
ContextThemeWrapper context = new ContextThemeWrapper(getActivity(), R.style.MyDialogTheme);
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
... ...
```

hope this help.